# RegEx move and change filename

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to move a lot of files in this directory and format:

```
/1.12.268/1.12.268_Hi_3D.jpg
```

To this directory and format:

```
/1.12.0268/1.12.0268_Hi_3D.jpg
```

I have managed to run a RegEx that created all the new folders for me:

```
ls 1* | find . -type d | awk '{print("mkdir "$1)}' | sed 's/[0-9][0-9][0-9]*/0&/2'
```

But I can't work out what regex to use to create a `mv` statement that will move and rename all the files to their new folders?

This is as close as I have come but the folders are reversed and the files are not getting renamed.

```
ls 1* | find . -type f | awk '{print("mv "$1" "$1)}' | sed 's/[0-9][0-9][0-9]*/0&/2'
```

I get this output:

```
mv ./1.12.0269/1.12.269_Low_Tech.gif ./1.12.269/1.12.269_Low_Tech.gif
mv ./1.14.0410/1.14.410_hi_3d.jpg ./1.14.410/1.14.410_hi_3d.jpg
mv ./1.14.0410/1.14.410_hi_tech.jpg ./1.14.410/1.14.410_hi_tech.jpg
mv ./1.14.0410/1.14.410_low_3d.png ./1.14.410/1.14.410_low_3d.png
mv ./1.14.0410/1.14.410_low_tech.png ./1.14.410/1.14.410_low_tech.png
mv ./1.14.0845/1.14.845_hi_3d.jpg ./1.14.845/1.14.845_hi_3d.jpg
mv ./1.14.0845/1.14.845_hi_tech.jpg ./1.14.845/1.14.845_hi_tech.jpg
mv ./1.14.0845/1.14.845_low_3d.png ./1.14.845/1.14.845_low_3d.png
mv ./1.14.0845/1.14.845_low_tech.png ./1.14.845/1.14.845_low_tech.png
```

When I in fact want this:

```
mv ./1.12.269/1.12.269_Low_Tech.gif ./1.12.0269/1.12.0269_Low_Tech.gif
mv ./1.14.410/1.14.410_hi_3d.jpg ./1.14.0410/1.14.0410_hi_3d.jpg
mv ./1.14.410/1.14.410_hi_tech.jpg ./1.14.0410/1.14.0410_hi_tech.jpg
mv ./1.14.410/1.14.410_low_3d.png ./1.14.0410/1.14.0410_low_3d.png
mv ./1.14.410/1.14.410_low_tech.png ./1.14.0410/1.14.0410_low_tech.png
mv ./1.14.845/1.14.845_hi_3d.jpg ./1.14.0845/1.14.0845_hi_3d.jpg
mv ./1.14.845/1.14.845_hi_tech.jpg ./1.14.0845/1.14.0845_hi_tech.jpg
mv ./1.14.845/1.14.845_low_3d.png ./1.14.0845/1.14.0845_low_3d.png
mv ./1.14.845/1.14.845_low_tech.png ./1.14.0845/1.14.0845_low_tech.png
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have dirty way to do this. Give it a try.

```
ls 1* | find . -type f | awk '{print("mv "$1" "$1)}' | sed 's/[0-9][0-9][0-9]*/0&/6' | sed 's/[0-9][0-9][0-9]*/0&/8'
```

Answer (score 1):

Is using `rename` an option? It's basically made for this kind of stuff.

If so, `rename -n 's/[0-9][0-9][0-9]/0$&/g'` should work for you. (The `-n` is just for debugging, remove it for the actual renaming).

Comment: That would work great on linux, but i failed to mention i was using a mac, my choice of CLI tools are as such - limited. Thanks for a neat solution though!